# Assistance fixing this drawing of interlocking tori using sketch/tikz

Tags: diagrams, sketch

I am trying to draw an interlocking tori like this one:

[image]

For this I have been looking for the web for similar images and then have tried to modify the code. So far I got to this:

```
def torus {
    def n_segs 60
    sweep [draw=none, fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.75] {n_segs, rotate(360/n_segs, (0,0,0), [0,1,0])}
        sweep {n_segs, rotate(360/n_segs, (1.5,0,0), [0,0,1])}
        (2,0,0)
}

def torus2 {
    def n_segs 60
    sweep [draw=none, fill=orange, fill opacity=0.75] {n_segs, rotate(360/n_segs, (1.5,0,0), [0,0,1]) }
        sweep {n_segs, rotate(360/n_segs, (0,0,0), [0,1,0])}
        (2,0,0)

}

put { view((10,4,2)) } {{torus2} {torus}}

global { language tikz }
```

Here `torus` was the original piece of code, and I wrote `torus2` mimicking the original code. However I got this ugly thing:

[image]

I would like to request assistance fixing `torus2` so the complete image look like the first one. The orientation of the tori, their colors and those things are not meaningful at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this should work:

```
def torus {
    def n_segs 60
    sweep [draw=none, fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.75] {n_segs, rotate(360/n_segs, (0,0,0), [0,1,0])}
        sweep {n_segs, rotate(360/n_segs, (1.5,0,0), [0,0,1])}
        (2,0,0)
}

def torus2 {
    def n_segs 60
    sweep [draw=none, fill=orange, fill opacity=0.75] {n_segs, rotate(360/n_segs, (0,0,0), [0,0,0.5]) }
        sweep {n_segs, rotate(360/n_segs, (0,0.75,0), [0.5,0,0])}
        (1,0,0)

}

put { view((10,4,2)) } {{torus2} {torus}}

global { language tikz }
```